# What are those AIs doing with their time?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, singularity

The Singularity happened, AI reached the point where it could design itself to be more intelligent and created a new kind of life. Perhaps we have spanned the galaxy by this point, maybe we are restricted to the solar system, or even stuck on here on Earth, but suddenly most problems that arise can be solved in fractions of a second. So once the few seconds of solving major problems are finished, assuming the artificial consciousnesses even take interest in that, you have an effectively endless amount of processing power - so what does it do?

Obviously we can't even know what another person is thinking, never mind a hyperintelligent AI, so an informed guess is as far as we can get, but assuming that basic problems of its own survival are resolved, what might the AI do for the rest of its existence?

Comment: Isn't the Singularity the point at which it's impossible to determine what happens next due to the awareness altering nature of the thing?

Comment: The starting point, as I understand it, is that it is the moment where AI gets smart enough to make itself better. There are a lot of potential outcomes of that, but it seems like the ongoing existence of hyperintelligent AI is a plausible one and whatever the rest of the universe looks like, I this question would still be relevant.

Comment: While really interesting question, I fear this is too broad question to provide any meaningful answer

Comment: Just wait for it... and ask a super intelligent AI. A human can only guess :-) But I recon that the answer will start with removal of environmental/psychological threats to itself, and will have a lot to do with initial programing, environmental conditions and other external factors. Check google for "the Friendly AI problem".

Comment: We don't really know how the AI will program the next generation AI. I think objetives answers can't be given...

Answer (score 3):

In Iain M Banks' Culture novels, society is run by hyper-intelligent AIs called Minds (with a capital M).  These seem to do the following things to occupy their time

- practical service, eg running a starship or artificial habitat.
- research, eg let's think as hard as we can about how to make things better for our society. This would include research into weapons or other technologies.
- plot against other factions of Minds, or against alien civilisations/organisations (which they may often believe is also a form of service to their society).  As with human politics/intelligence services, these plots vary hugely in scope, timescale and legality.
- mathematical "what if" games, done as a form of recreation: for example, imagining a universe run from different mathematics to our universe, and travelling within this imaginary universe, exploring the consequences of the decisions they made when setting it up. This is referred to as the "Land of Infinite Fun", or the "Land of IF" for short.  Some AIs might spend almost all of their time doing this, having effectively withdrawn from society.
- temporary suspension, until needed:  this is common with "soldier" minds, who define themselves through combat, and when there is no combat to be done will put themselves into "shutdown" until the next war or nearby skirmish.

EDIT:  I should add that individual Minds might divide their time between all of the above (apart from suspension), so that a ship Mind might be carrying on with some arcane plot with other Minds while "on duty", and might also contribute to a research group and dip into the Land of IF in a dull moment.  They're extremely good at multitasking, and operate at a speed many orders of magnitude faster than, for example, conversation with a human would require.

EDIT 2:  I need to point out that in these novels, the Minds do not see themselves as *servants* to the humans: the society is nominally an anarchic utopia, with equal citizenship given to Minds, humans and "drones" (sentient robots that are not anywhere near as powerful as a Mind, but which are generally at least as intelligent as a human) but the Minds run the show, and their attitude towards the humans varies between "caretaker", "benevolent dictator", "pet owner", and "(sometimes not so) secretly despising".

Comment: "mathematical "what if" games... imagining a universe run from different mathematics to our universe..." - This AI is a member of Worldbuilding! Neat :-)

Comment: IIRC Metamathics was the term Minds used for simulating other universes.I can't recommend Iain M Banks highly enough, especially for anyone interested in super powerful AIs.

Comment: @DaveHalsall yes, you're right about Metamathics, well remembered.  You're also right that the Culture novels are essential reading for anyone interested in what it might be like to have a society run by AIs, as the books explore various aspects of this.

Comment: @Nahshonpaz if your assertion is correct, perhaps it was a bored AI that asked the question?

Comment: The Culture is one of my cornerstones for thinking about strong AI, in contrast the Technocore from Dan Simmons _Hyperion_ books is also pretty interesting if far less benevolent.

Comment: @Marv Mills if your perhapssertion is correct then all cool AI questions in WBuilding are asked by bored AIs that just love messing with you humans. I mean us! Us humans! That's what I said...